# BizTalk - RabbitMQ WCF send port error of File not found?

Tags: rabbitmq, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to setup my BizTalk server 2010 to communicate with RabbitMQ.
Followed the link below to setup the send port for this [BizTalk Server And RabbitMQ](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7401.biztalk-server-and-rabbitmq.aspx)

After doing this while saving the properties
Getting below error while setting up send port properties in Biztalk 2010 server.

> WCF-Custom Transport Properties
>
> Error saving properties.
>
> (System.ArgumentException) The specified address is invalid.
>
> (System.ArgumentException) Cannot obtain scheme from binding to validate address.
>
> (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException) Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) Could not load file or assembly 'RabbitMQ.Client, Version=3.6.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89e7d7c5feba84ce' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please help what to do next?

Comment: Did you add the bindingextensions to your machine.config files, keeping in mind the x86 & x64 runnable host instances?

Comment: Yes I have added it on machine.config. Put it like -- <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        …
        <add  name="RabbitMQBinding"
          type="RabbitMQ.ServiceModel.RabbitMQBindingSection, RabbitMQ.ServiceModel, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=1751e286f1ab778d"/>
      </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>

Comment: The assembly is also in the GAC?